# Database connection in umbraco

Tags: .net, umbraco

I was installing umbraco and installed successfully, but forgot to configure with database and now i don't know how to connect with database in which file. can somebody explain me whole process of database connection with details

Comment: You mean by installing that you already run Umbraco for the first time and entered the user credentials and leave everything else standard?

Comment: Yes, same happened, Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: The easiest way is to start over with a new fresh project and installation. Then you know everything will be installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is in your web.config, see the connectionStrings default it use the \App_Data\Umbraco.sdf

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Umbraco.sdf;Flush Interval=1;" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    <!-- Important: If you're upgrading Umbraco, do not clear the connection string / provider name during your web.config merge. -->
  </connectionStrings>
```