# I forgot to provide database connection in umbraco

Tags: .net, database-connection, umbraco

While installing umbraco i forgot to provide database configuration and now i want to have database with proper that connection. I checked web.config file but couldn't understand where should i put connection and i don't want to reinstall unbarco. Please help me with this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database connection in umbraco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218675/database-connection-in-umbraco)

Answer (score 1):

If you already installed Umbraco to a database, you can't just switch connection strings and expect everything to be fine. You asked the same question just before and got the same answer - reinstalling is your best option, since Umbraco does a bunch of database setup when installing. Which shouldn't be a problem at all, since you've only just installed it, right?

The connection string is in web.config under `<connectionStrings>` named `umbracoDbDSN`, but just pointing it to a different database will NOT fix anything.

If you want to move your data to SQL Server, this may help you though: http://carlosmartinezt.com/2014/03/umbraco-migrate-from-sql-ce-to-sql-server/